# JSF based framework for touch websites

Tags: java, android, jsf, mobile, mobile-website

What is a good JSF based framework for developing web sites optimized for touch smartphones (i.e. with android)?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are already a JSF developer you can create a website using the core JSF only with JQuery mobile.  PrimeFaces for mobile, ICEFaces for mobile and others are good but the  generated code is unnecessarily HUGE.

I think using just JSF without any other component library is the way to go considering that with a mobile device you a pretty much limited visually.  See this guide on how to create a mobile website with just JSF and JQuery Mobile.  (BTW PrimeFaces mobile uses the same JQuery Mobile).

http://kahimyang.info/kauswagan/HowtoBlogs.xhtml?b=803

Answer (score 4):

PrimeFaces Mobile, successor of TouchFaces is under heavy development, initial demos are revealed;

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/mobile/index.jsf

Comment: Now that is much better than touchfaces. Works great. Without visible bugs.

Answer (score 1):

MobileJSF seems to aim towards alternative Renderkits (for WML, etc.) but modern mobile devices are nothing else than devices with HTML Browsers.

Developing mobile web applications is a lot about visual presentation on small screensizes. Another thing is to achieve usability on a touchscreen (big fingers, small buttons). I havent found any apropriate JSF library offering nice looking components for modern mobile devices that integrates cleanly in the sourrounding application. So we spend some effort in optimizing CSS. You could switch the stylesheet depending on the mobile device.

Anyway, to simulate iPhone Look&Feel in a web application you might take a look at the Touchfaces subproject of PrimeFaces (http://www.primefaces.org), though I find it not too useful until today.

Comment: It makes sense. Pitty touchfaces isn't working good enough (on my Galaxy S the showcase is buggy). It would've been nice to have something like richfaces or primefaces for touch devices, that works properly.

Comment: @Benchik, According toe the primeface roadmap (http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/wiki/Roadmap), a complete overhaul of touchfaces is planned to be released around May. If you can wait that long it might be worth a look.

Comment: @Benchik You still are free to adjust the HTML RenderKit of any given Library like Richfaces. I guess it'll be a lot of work but, depending on your business case, may be worth the effort.